# Multiple line image slider with buttons

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a website that should have image sliders with clickable buttons that flip to the next image.

I was able to make a single slider / page, but as I have no experience in coding yet, I ran into difficulties when I was trying make multiple sliders following each other directly. The buttons of a certain slider started to mix up, and target other sliders too, or only the first one, but not the way I wanted..

So I started copying and repeating the same lines of code and applying them to groups of images separately.
I also want some text to flip together with the images, so I grouped the text and images together with the buttons, and finally I ended up having a lot of repetition, and way too long codes. :-)

Right now it works, but I assume that there is a much easier, solution, that would make my code a lot shorter.

Can someone help me with:

1. Having one good java script, that doesn't mix up the targets, when having multiple sliders?
2. Having only one "buttons"/slider instead of copying them to all the "containergrid"s groups, but still flipping the text together with the image?

Thanks, and sorry for the long code. :)

```
    <div class="content">

<!---THE FIRST SLIDER--->

        <div class="slider_1">
            <div class="slides_1">
                <div class="containergrid">
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="maindescription">Description</p>
                        <p class="year">2017</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imgbutton">
                        <img class="img_1_1">
                        <div class="button">
                            <button class="prev"
                              onclick="plusDivs1(-1)"></button>
                            <button class="next" 
                              onclick="plusDivs1(1)"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides_1">
                 <div class="containergrid">
                     <div class="description">
                         <p class="maindescription">Description</p>
                         <p class="year">2017</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="imgbutton">
                         <img class="img_1_2">
                         <div class="button">
                            <button class="prev"
                              onclick="plusDivs1(-1)"></button>
                            <button class="next" 
                              onclick="plusDivs1(1)"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!---THE SECOND SLIDER--->

        <div class="slider_2">
            <div class="slides_2">
                <div class="containergrid">
                    <div class="description">
                        <p class="maindescription">Description</p>
                        <p class="year">2017</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imgbutton">
                        <img class="img_2_1">
                        <div class="button">
                            <button class="prev"
                              onclick="plusDivs1(-1)"></button>
                            <button class="next" 
                              onclick="plusDivs1(1)"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides_2">
                 <div class="containergrid">
                     <div class="description">
                         <p class="maindescription">Description</p>
                         <p class="year">2017</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="imgbutton">
                         <img class="img_2_2">
                         <div class="button">
                            <button class="prev"
                              onclick="plusDivs1(-1)"></button>
                            <button class="next" 
                              onclick="plusDivs1(1)"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

```
    <script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs1(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs1(n) {
            showDivs1(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function showDivs1(n) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides_1");
            if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs2(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs2(n) {
            showDivs2(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function showDivs2(n) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides_2");
            if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would just have to pass a reference to your slides into the `showDivs` function, so you can keep the clicks independent of one another. You'd still have to initialize each slider separately.

```
function plusDivs(slider, n) {
    showDivs(slider, slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showDivs(slider, index) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slider);
    if (index > x.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (index < 1) {
      slideIndex = x.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";
  }

  // Initialize the sliders
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showDivs('slides_1', slideIndex);
  showDivs('slides_2', slideIndex);
```

In your HTML you just need to pass the reference to the `plusDivs` function:

`onclick="plusDivs('slides_1', 1)"`

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/0q3w1h2z/) showing a working example